# Deconstructing a column in R by matching similar rows?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, confidence-interval, bigdata

I'm currently working on a project where I have a huge dataframe, 16196 obs of 25 variables. The goal is to eliminate any outliers that might be in the dataframe for each specific treatment. The problem is that the column with the treatments has every treatment in there and each treatment has a different length that they last. Let me show you an example.

**val_lvl2: chr  "Cervical Fusion (Spinal Fusion)" "Non-Surgical Treatment" "Non-Surgical Treatment" "Non-Surgical Treatment" ...**

**prd_num_of_days_num: num  167 46 46 46 167 46 46 46 167 46 ...**

output is from str(z_combined_cost_dtrmnt)

We can see that val_lvl2 has all the treatments(100+ not shown). And  prd_num_of_days_num has the length of that specific treatment. Now what I want to do is combine ALL(there are more in there) the "Cervical Fusion" data and the "Non-Surgical Treatment" data into there own little dataframes. After that I want to create a 95% confidence on the length of the treatments then remove any rows of data that don't fall into that CI. Then bring back the dataframes so that we have 1 large one again but the outliers in each treatment are gone.

I would appreciate any help as I really don't know where to start with this since there seems like no easy way to break down the dataframe the way I want to.

Currently thinking about using the aggregate function.

agg <- aggregate(z_combined_cost_dtrmnt$prd_num_of_days_num, by = list(val_lvl2 = z_combined_cost_dtrmnt$val_lvl2), by = list(val_lvl3=z_combined_cost_dtrmnt$val_lvl3), FUN = SD)

However that gives this error: Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : formal argument "by" matched by multiple actual arguments

TL/DR

Big Data Frame -->

Smaller Data Frames based on unique values in val_lvl2 keeping in mind that there are similar unique values i.e multiple instances of "Cervical Fusion" should be in the same small data frame -->

Create a 95% CI based on the prd_num_of_days_num(length of treatment) for each small data frame -->

Remove the entire row for each unique values if prd_num_of_days_num is outside of CI -->

merge small data frames with no outliers into one big data frame again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Hey @StevenBeaupré! My current idea is to possibly try to aggregate. Here's what I have so far.


 agg <- aggregate(z_combined_cost_dtrmnt$prd_num_of_days_num, by = list(val_lvl2 = z_combined_cost_dtrmnt$val_lvl2), by = list(val_lvl3=z_combined_cost_dtrmnt$val_lvl3), FUN = SD)

However that gives this error:
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) :
  formal argument "by" matched by multiple actual arguments

Answer (score 0):

So you have one dataframe (df), with 25 variables, and you want to break it down into X smaller dataframes, x being the number of unique treatments, each of them containing the remaining 24 variables, but only containing one type of treatment. Correct?

```
treatment1 <- df[df$val_lvl2 == "Cervical Fusion (Spinal Fusion)"]
treatment2 <- df[ds$val_lvl2 =="Non-Surgical Treatment"]
# etc...
```

There are more concise, and 'better' ways to do it, but I think this is where you should start to get a grasp of how to organize data in R.

Comment: Yes exactly! I had actually thought about doing what you just did up there. But since there are about 150 treatments in val_lvl2 I was hoping to maybe find something a little more efficient and general.

Something that would kind of follow this path.

Big Data Frame --> Smaller Data Frames based on unique val_lvl2 --> Create 95 CI  based on prd_num_of_days_num for each small data frame --> Remove entire row if prd_num_of_days_num  outside of CI --> merge small data frames with no outliers into one big data frame again.

Not sure why the text isn't spacing out how I want it too...

Comment: Sorry but it's a bit hard to wrap my head around what exactly it is you want to accomplish. I suggest you delete this post, and make a new one with a small scale example code that can easily be replicated. To do what I did above in a quick way for all your cases, try this: `treatments <- unique(df$val_lvl2)

for (i in c(1:length(treatments))){

    assign(paste("df_", treatments[[i]], sep=''), df[df == treatments[[i]])
    
}`

Comment: Thanks! I'll see where that little snippet gets me and get back to this board if I can't squeeze a solution out of what's been posted. It's a little complicated so I appreciate the effort!